# Setting and Testing SMTP in Windows7

Tags: windows-7, smtp, sendmail

I am using SMTP service to send mail through my application
This application is working on all O/S
My O/S is Windows 7
I have added my SMTP server name etc in the SMTP settings
But there is no mailroot folder in c:\inetpub
Also the mails are not being sent
How do I test that the SMTP service is active.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the telnet command to interact with your SMTP server.

```
telnet localhost 25
```

or

```
telnet localhost 587
```

depending on what port you have set up. If the SMTP service has been setup correctly then it will answer with a welcome message.